# Remove all words that appear n+ times without deleting the lines or change the file order

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file that consists of sections, each with two header lines and a body line consisting of space-separated words. An example looks as follows:

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-1:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-2:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        ConsoleSetup        REMINST     SCCMContentLib$     SCCMContentLibC$        SEFPKGC$        SEFPKGD$        SEFPKGE$        SEFSIG$     Source      UpdateServicesPackages      WsusContent     backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-BE-03:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2     print$
```

I want to delete *from the body lines* all words that occur *three or more times*.

- I want to delete *all* occurences, not just "all occurences after the first two".
- The tokens to be matched are the space-separated "words", e.g. `print$` as a whole and not just the alphanumerical part `print`.
- The matching should only apply to "whole words", i.e. no partial string matches. E.g. any occurence of `backup` would only count towards removal of `backup`, but not of `backup2`.
- The header lines (`Shares for ...` and `[--- Listable Shares ---]`) are not to be considered.

The desired output for the above input would look as follows:

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-1:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
                
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-2:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        ConsoleSetup        REMINST     SCCMContentLib$     SCCMContentLibC$        SEFPKGC$        SEFPKGD$        SEFPKGE$        SEFSIG$     Source      UpdateServicesPackages      WsusContent
Shares for DED-SHD-BE-03:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
                        print$
```

As you can see, only the words `backup` and `backup2` are removed as they occur in the body lines of three sections. However, `Shares`, `for` and `Listable` in the section header lines remain untouched because the header lines should not be considered for editing.

Some notes:

- The files have sizes in the range of 100kB to 1MB.
- I have found solutions like `awk '++A[$0] < 3'` but that would keep the first two occurences and looks at entire lines.
- I am not looking specifically for an Awk-based solution, anything (except Perl ;)) is fine.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152072/discussion-on-question-by-pwrsheller-remove-all-words-that-appear-n-times-witho); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I have performed a major rewrite of your question in the hope that your intended requirements are easier to understand. If you think the current form contradicts with you wishes, feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the requirement covers files of up to 1MB, there are a couple of array inversions in this to improve efficiency. Because we are deleting words, I did not thing it was important to retain exact spacing, so each word in a replaced row is just preceded by TAB.

It is a Bash script containing a single shell function, which itself contains a single awk program. It takes one input file argument, and outputs to stdout.

I am not sure how you might want to verify the results. I had plenty of debug during development: it would be easy (for example) to log to stderr the deleted words, with their frequency.

```
#! /bin/bash

delByFreq () {

    local Awk='
BEGIN { SEP = "|"; Freq = 3; }
#.. Store every input line.
{ Line[NR] = $0; }
#.. Do not look for words on header lines.
/^Shares for / { next; }
/--- Listable Shares ---/ { next; }

#.. Keep an index to row/column of every unique word.
#.. So like: Ref ["backup2"] = "|2|3|5|1|5|7";
function Refer (row, txt, Local, f) {
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; ++f)
        Ref[$(f)] = Ref[$(f)] SEP row SEP f;
}
{ Refer( NR, $0); }

#.. Rearrange field indexes by line.
#.. So like: Del[row] = "|3|7|11"; for field numbers.
function refByLine (Local, word, j, n, V) {
    for (word in Ref) {
        n = split (Ref[word], V, SEP);
        if (n <= 2 * Freq) continue;
        for (j = 2; j < n; j += 2)
            Del[V[j]] = Del[V[j]] SEP (V[j+1]);
    }
}
#.. For every line with deletions, cross off the frequent words.
function Deletions (Local, row, j, f, n, V, X) {
    for (row in Del) {
        split (Del[row], V, SEP);
        split ("", X, FS); for (j = 2; j in V; ++j) X[V[j]];
        #.. Rebuild the line in field order. 
        split (Line[row], V, FS); Line[row] = "";
        for (j = 1; j in V; ++j)
            if (! (j in X)) Line[row] = Line[row] "\t" V[j];
    }
}
function Output (Local, r) {
    for (r = 1; r in Line; ++r) printf ("%s\n", Line[r]);
}
END { refByLine( ); Deletions( ); Output( ); }
'
    awk -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" ) "${1}"
}

    delByFreq "${1}"
```

Comment: Wow. Much code more than I expected. It works like a charm. You've helped me a lot and I'm glad you already inspired someone!

Comment: I think I've seen AWK scripts stored in files with a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` hashbang at the front. I can't remember if there were some issues with that, or if you had a reason not to do that, but it might look at least a bit nicer than embedding the AWK program in a string in a shell script.

Comment: @ilkkachu  I am well aware of that usage, but many of my more complex Bash scripts require multiple awk invocations. My clients generally can't deal with a cluster of associated files, paths etc. So I wrap Awk like this to simplify release and maintenance, and so the OP can embed it into their own script cleanly. I also usually have some need to deal with args and redirections, which I much prefer to do in Bash.

Comment: @ilkkachu FWIW I'd also never use a shebang to call awk (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001) but I'd just call awk directly from the shell script or from a shell function within the script, I wouldn't store the script in a variable first. I believe people have said in the past they use variables like this so their editor of choice can do code highlighting properly but I don't recall the details.

Comment: @EdMorton  I don't like embedding the awk code directly in a command line because that widely separates the `awk -v -F` stuff from the file names and redirections. Also, it muddles up the two styles of indentation. If not a local variable, I could also embed the Awk code in a function that just cat'd it as a HereDoc. I use `awk -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" )` so the command in `ps` only shows `awk -f /dev/fd/63`. I grew up on Solaris, which would show the whole of my 3000-byte direct Awk code in `ps`, and seriously annoys SysAdmins.

Comment: @Ed  Putting the awk code in the command but as a separate block of lines does not do it for me -- it still leaves it all visible on the command line. I'm looking at a 270-line awk code (18 declared functions) and an awk command-line with 25 args: 4 `-v`, 1 `-f`, plus it reads 5 files where I have to set `Id`, `FS` and `RS` args differently for each filename -- I need to separate those components. I'm considering HereDocs but that is likely UUOC. The complete Bash script is around 2600 lines, 300 of that is Awk.

Comment: Never mind, I think I just understood what you're saying. I thought we were still talking about using a shebang to call awk or not from a shell script but you're talking about why you store your awk code in a shell variable so while I thought ["command line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772465/remove-all-words-that-appear-n-times-without-deleting-the-lines-or-change-the-f/772495?noredirect=1#comment1475326_772495) was about the call to the shell script that calls awk, you're talking about "command line" as the call to awk inside that shell script.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why you store your scripts in variables, I understand now.

Comment: I assume you already wrap your large awk script in a shell function but something else to consider regarding keeping all the awk options and arguments together would be to store THOSE in array variables rather than storing the script in a scalar variable: `awkOpts=( -v x='foo bar' -F, ); awkArgs=( RS='^$' file1 RS='\n' ORS='xxxx' file2 )` and then using them as `awk "${awkOpts[@]}" 'script' "${awkArgs[@]}"`. It wouldn't solve the problem you described with `ps` output on Solaris but idk if that's still a problem for you or not.

Comment: I'm not sure why I feel that'd be better than saving the script in a variable - I'm having a hard time getting my head around that one, maybe because I'm used to the shell adage that [Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) which probably doesn't apply in this case as that's talking about shell code while this is awk code.

Comment: @EdMorton, right, I think I may have seen you say that about `-f` hashbangs before. I get the thing about having scripts that embed redirections (or something that passes the same filename twice to `awk`). Here, it just came to mind since somehow, putting multiline scripts in a single-quoted string seems awkward in a way. It requires one to be really careful about not using single quotes inside the script, as the consequences would likely be rather confusing. Not that those are too common in AWK, unless you print one, but still, it's just one character that can accidentally end the quoting.

Comment: Python-style `'''` quotes or Perl-style heredocs that can be assigned into a variable would be much nicer. But of course the shell doesn't have them. I would be tempted to just put the AWK code in a different file, then call `awk -f file.awk whatever...` from a shell script is necessary. That would feel cleaner in a way, but also awkward, if not only because of the issue of knowing the path to the separate script file. Meh. As for code highlighting, I think for many simple editors a separate file would help? Maybe a smart one could be told to highlight a particular string using another lang.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, I suppose, as one option, one could use `awk -f /dev/fd/9 9<<'EOF' whatever...` and then drop the AWK code in the here-doc after that. If that's any better, idk.

Comment: @ilkkachu I agree that putting multiline scripts in a single-quoted string seems awkward (and I personally wouldn't do it but I now understand Pauls reasoning) but in terms of a single quote in the script, that's also a constraint if you did `awk 'script' file`, you can't put a single quote in your script that way either. FWIW I use `\047` everywhere I need a single quote in an awk script, even if it's stored in a file where I could use a literal `'`, just for consistency and so I know I can copy a script out of a file to use inline (or vice-versa) some other time without tripping over that.

Comment: @EdMorton  I have had clients who "correct" my single-quotes and then complain my script has syntax errors. I sometimes use Python-style `'''` to put them off -- in bash that just attaches an empty string at the start or end. I declare `DQ="\042"` `SQ="\047"` upfront, either with `-v` or in `BEGIN`.

Comment: FWIW I always use `\"` as there's no problem with that in any context and I always use a literal `\047` because you can always use it in any comtext, e.g. in a string `x = "a\047b"` or in a regexp `x ~ /a\047b/` vs `x = "a"SQ"b"` and `x ~ "a"SQ"b"`, the latter of which would mean you'd also have to double up escapes on any other part of the dynamic regexp `x ~ /a\+\047b/` vs `x ~ "a\\+"SQ"b"`. Hope you charge your clients double for "corrections"!

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk` for the 4th arg to `split()` to save the strings that match the `FS` so we can have the same spacing in the output as was present in the output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ begFld = 1 }
/^Shares for/ { begFld = 3 }
/\[--- Listable Shares ---]/ { begFld = NF+1 }
NR == FNR {
    for ( i=begFld; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        cnt[$i]++
    }
    next
}
{
    split($0,unused,FS,seps)
    out = seps[0]
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        out = out ( (i >= begFld) && (cnt[$i] >= 3) ? "" : $i ) seps[i]
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-1:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-2:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        ConsoleSetup        REMINST     SCCMContentLib$     SCCMContentLibC$        SEFPKGC$        SEFPKGD$        SEFPKGE$        SEFSIG$     Source      UpdateServicesPackages      WsusContent
Shares for DED-SHD-BE-03:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
                   print$
```

You can do the same in any awk with a `while ( match(...) )` loop instead of `split(...); for (...)` , it'd just be a couple more lines of code, e.g. this will work in any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ begFld = 1 }
/^Shares for/ { begFld = 3 }
/\[--- Listable Shares ---]/ { begFld = NF+1 }
NR == FNR {
    for ( i=begFld; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        cnt[$i]++
    }
    next
}
{
    i = 0
    out = ""
    while ( match($0,/[^ \t]+/) ) {
        sep = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
        fld = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        out = out sep ( (++i >= begFld) && (cnt[fld] >= 3) ? "" : fld )
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print out $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-1:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-2:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        ConsoleSetup        REMINST     SCCMContentLib$     SCCMContentLibC$        SEFPKGC$        SEFPKGD$        SEFPKGE$        SEFSIG$     Source      UpdateServicesPackages      WsusContent
Shares for DED-SHD-BE-03:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
                   print$
```

---

EDIT: @Paul_Pedant and I were chatting in the comments about the pros/cons of reading the input into an array and then processing it in the `END` section as [his script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772495/133219) does vs reading the input file twice as my script above does so I put mine in a shell script and added a bash shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    { begFld = 1 }
    ...
        print out
    }
' "$1" "$1"
```

then created an input file that's 1 million copies of the OPs 9-line input file by doing this:

```
$ awk '{r=(NR>1 ? r ORS : "") $0} END{for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) print r}' file > file1m
```

then timed executing my script on it:

```
$ time ./tst_ed.sh file1m > ed.out

real    1m3.814s
user    0m57.781s
sys     0m0.265s
```

but when I tried to run Pauls script on it:

```
$ time ./tst_paul.sh file1m > paul.out
```

my laptop started to sound like a helicopter taking off so after 5 minutes I interrupted it then waited about 3 more minutes for my laptop to settle down again.

I then tried both on a 100k reps file:

```
$ awk '{r=(NR>1 ? r ORS : "") $0} END{for (i=1; i<=100000; i++) print r}' file > file100k
```

```
$ time ./tst_ed.sh file100k > ed.out                                            
real    0m6.035s
user    0m5.875s
sys     0m0.031s
```

```
$ time ./tst_paul.sh file100k > paul.out
```

but I again had to eventually interrupt Pauls (I gave this one 10 minutes).

I then tried a 10k reps file:

```
$ awk '{r=(NR>1 ? r ORS : "") $0} END{for (i=1; i<=10000; i++) print r}' file > file10k
```

```
$ time ./tst_ed.sh file10k > ed.out                                             
real    0m0.783s
user    0m0.609s
sys     0m0.045s
```

```
$ time ./tst_paul.sh file10k > paul.out

real    0m1.039s
user    0m0.921s
sys     0m0.031s
```

This time I got output from both so I ran a `diff -b` on them and discovered that the output is different -

```
$ diff -b ed.out paul.out |head
1c1
< Shares for
---
> Shares for DED-SHD-ED-1:
4c4
< Shares for
---
> Shares for DED-SHD-ED-2:
7c7
< Shares for
```

Mine removes the duplicate values at the end of the `Shares for ...` lines while Paul's doesn't. idk which would be the desired behavior for the OP or if it even matters, it may just be unrealistic input.

I then tried 1k reps:

```
$ awk '{r=(NR>1 ? r ORS : "") $0} END{for (i=1; i<=1000; i++) print r}' file > file1k
```

```
$ time ./tst_ed.sh file1k > ed.out

real    0m0.133s
user    0m0.077s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time ./tst_paul.sh file1k > paul.out
```

```
real    0m0.133s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.046s
```

and 100 reps:

```
$ awk '{r=(NR>1 ? r ORS : "") $0} END{for (i=1; i<=100; i++) print r}' file > file100
```

```
$ time ./tst_ed.sh file100 > ed.out

real    0m0.080s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

```
$ time ./tst_paul.sh file100 > paul.out

real    0m0.081s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

so it looks like for around 1k or less repetitions of the OPs data (i.e. up to about a 10k line input file) whether you store the data in memory and parse in the END section or read the input file twice is about a wash regarding execution speed (once you're into the 10ths of a second execution time who cares?) and at about 10k repetitions (about 100k input lines) the read-twice approach is a bit faster but both are fast at around 1 sec execution time. Once you get to larger input file sizes than that, though, you really don't want to be trying to store it in memory.

Comment: Slight disadvantage in reading the input file twice (although probably mitigated by caching). (1MB is expected). cnt[] >=3 specified. But less than half the LoC I came up with. Very tidy use of the GNU/awk split extension.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant good catch on the `3`. I've now changed `cnt[$i] > 1` to `cnt[$i] >= 3` and added a version that'd work in any awk. As for reading the file twice being a disadvantage - the disadvantage is that you then can't process input coming from a pipe but the advantage is that you can then process arbitrarily large files and, in terms of execution speed, awk allocates arrays in exponentially larger chunks of memory and so will slow down significantly as an array gets larger and so if the file is huge then reading it twice may end up faster than reading it once and storing it all in memory

Comment: I will try throwing a few MB of plain text at both -- some test suite data, but I would need to do a frequency count first.

Comment: Thank you again for your effort @EdMorton. I like the few LoC approach

Comment: You're welcome. I thought you might actually like the simplicity and "getting the output you asked for" more :-). It'd actually be less (and simpler) code still if it wasn't retaining the white space from the input - that was the only slightly tricky part about the problem!

Comment: @EdMorton  I tried a bulk test, ripping words of six or more characters out of a plain text, ending up with 20,000 lines, 162K words, 1.48 MB. Frequency count gave me the top 5 words with Freq > 400, total 2658 deleted words on 2351 lines. Runs in 2.3 seconds on a Laptop, which I can live with.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks for the info! Did you happen to test both of our scripts to get a comparison if it's faster to read into an array vs open the file twice (and check if both produce the same output)? Ah, I just noticed it sounds like the script you tested wasn't the one for this problem but for something else.

Comment: @EdMorton  The other advantage of all-in-memory is that any known Awk can update-in-situ without a package: just loop `print Line[j] > FILENAME;` after fixing data. In fact, you can read a list of filenames from stdin, read in each file using `getline`, and update as many files in situ as you like with one process.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant sure, I do that if/when it's useful to do so and the input is small enough to fit in memory.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I just added some timing data to the end of my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton  I used the same script for my timings (with a little extra debug). The difference in the data was that I didn't fake up any of the header lines (containing the `Shares` word) -- my input data was 20,000 solid lines of data to be de-duplicated, not just 33% of the total lines.